# How to get language parameter from current site by php and add it to variable

Tags: php

I need to get the language parameter from the current page and its meta tag by php.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de-DE" />
```

After I have the language de-DE or en-US, I want to add the 1060 for de-DE and 1061 for en-US to the value

```
if (function_exists('ditty_news_ticker')) {ditty_news_ticker(1060);}?></div>
```

It´s not a big deal for me, to do this with JS, but I have no idea to do this with php. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What is the current page ? The one your server created ?

Comment: yes, the server creates multiple sites with different content language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get_meta_tags();

All you need to do is supply it with a link and it'll output the meta data as an array.
e.g

```
get_meta_tags('http://www.google.com');
```

Comment: Thank you! But I need it from the current site not from an external site.